# checking if iptables are set on a system in script

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, iptables, programming

I'm writing a script in bash and I need to check if iptables are set...I have this:

```
if [ `iptables-save | grep '^\-' | wc -l` > 0 ]
then
    echo "Iptables already set, skipping..........!"
else
    Here the iptables get set
```

But it's not working as expected....

**PROBLEM:**

I did `iptables-save` and it created this:

```
$iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Tue Oct 16 02:48:41 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [2:266]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2:116]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Oct 16 02:48:41 2018
```

So if I run the test it finds that they are already set.... like here:

```
(root@notemDEB78)-(03:12:20)-(/home/something78/Bash_Programming_2018)
$s.sh
Iptables already set....skipping!!!!!
(root@notemDEB78)-(03:12:25)-(/home/something78/Bash_Programming_2018)
$iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination 

(root@notemDEB78)-(03:16:41)-(/home/something78/Bash_Programming_2018)
$iptables-save | grep '^\-' | wc -l
0
```

**QUESTION:**

- Why does it always find the that iptables are set when the obviously
  are not
- Do you have a better/working way of checking if `iptables` are set....my system is `Debian 9`

  bash -version
  GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
  Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html

**AS TO POSSIBLE DUPLICATE:**

> This question is also asking if anyone has a better way to check if
>   iptables are set for a script in bash....

EDIT:

By set I mean that iptables have been set like this:

```
if [[ `iptables-save | grep '^\-' | wc -l` > 0 ]]
    then
        echo "Iptables already set....skipping!!!!!"
    else
        if [ "$PORT" = "" ]
        then
            echo "Port not set for iptables exiting"
            echo -n "Setting port now, insert portnumber: "
            read port
            PORT=$port
        fi
        if [ ! -f /etc/iptables.test.rules ]
        then
            touch /etc/iptables.test.rules
        else
            cat /dev/null > /etc/iptables.test.rules
        fi

        cat << EOT >> /etc/iptables.test.rules
        *filter

        # Allows all loopback (lo0) traffic and drop all traffic to 127/8 that doesn't use lo0
        -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
        -A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

        # Accepts all established inOAUTH_TOKEN=d6637f7ccf109a0171a2f55d21b6ca43ff053616bound connections
        -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

        # Allows all outbound traffic
        # You could modify this to only allow certain traffic
        -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

        # Allows HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere (the normal ports for websites)
        -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
        -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

        # Allows SSH connections
        # The --dport number is the same as in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
        -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport $PORT -j ACCEPT

        # Now you should read up on iptables rules and consider whether ssh access
        # for everyone is really desired. Most likely you will only allow access from certain IPs.

        # Allow ping
        #  note that blocking other types of icmp packets is considered a bad idea by some
        #  remove -m icmp --icmp-type 8 from this line to allow all kinds of icmp:
        #  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22711
        -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

        # log iptables denied calls (access via dmesg command)
        -A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7

        # Reject all other inbound - default deny unless explicitly allowed policy:
        -A INPUT -j REJECT
        -A FORWARD -j REJECT

        COMMIT
EOT
        sed "s/^[ \t]*//" -i /etc/iptables.test.rules ## remove tabs and spaces
        /sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.test.rules || echo "iptables-restore failed"; exit 127
        /sbin/iptables-save > /etc/iptables.up.rules || echo "iptables-save failed"; exit 127
        printf "#!/bin/bash\n/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules" > /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables ## create a script to run iptables on startup
        chmod +x /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables || echo "cmod +x failed"; exit 127
    fi
```

Comment: The `>` in ``[ `iptables-save | grep '^\-' | wc -l` > 0 ]`` is for redirection. You redirected the output of `[ ... ]` to a file named `0`. If you want to compare, use `-gt` or `\>`.

Comment: @muru the question is also if there is anyone with a better way to check if iptables are set like in the title

Comment: Meh. At any rate, the problem with the existing script is handled in the duplicate, so just edit it out.

Comment: @somethingSomething It depends on what "already set" means to you... Can you clarify? Are you looking for any rules at all or specific rules?

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger update the question with what I do with iptables

Comment: @FilipeBrandenburger not set = no iptables

Comment: @support  what is wrong with you people, this is clearly not the same/dupe as the other question

Comment: @admin  what is wrong with you people, this is clearly not the same/dupe as the other question

Comment: @slm  what is wrong with you people, this is clearly not the same/dupe as the other question

Comment: @terdon  what is wrong with you people, this is clearly not the same/dupe as the other question

Comment: @Michael Mrozek the reason I'm so pissed is that muru was condenscending and rude and then he got all these people agreeing with him and a downvote

Comment: I agree this question has almost nothing in common with suggested duplicate. Yesterday I've voted to reopen it; still one vote is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible simplification is to use the return of `grep` itself as the condition, `grep` will exit with code 0 (for "success") only if there are matches. No need to count lines since you're looking for *any* match.

Also, you don't need to escape the `-` with a `\`, since it's not a meta-character for grep regular expressions.

You can pass `grep` a `-q` argument, so it doesn't print the lines that match (only exits with an appropriate exit code depending on whether any lines matched.)

```
if /sbin/iptables-save | grep -q '^-'; then
    echo "Iptables already set....skipping!!!!!"
else
    # set up iptables here
fi
```

I think checking output of `iptables-save` to check whether any rules were set up is OK, I can't think of another way that's as reliable or that's simpler.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the answer....... greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The `iptables` command has its own way of checking the existence of a particular rule with `-C` option:

> `-C, --check chain rule-specification`
>
> Check whether a rule matching the specification does exist in the selected chain. This command uses the same logic as -D to find a matching entry, but does not alter the existing iptables configuration and uses its exit code to indicate success or failure.

Example:

```
if ! iptables -C INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT; then
     iptables -A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT
fi
```

Your current script checks if there are any rules in the table, but if you want to write reliable script you may want/need to check all rules one by one since other programs can interact with `iptables` too.